# Performing motion tracking and depth sensor reading with Tango simultaneously

Tags: android, google-project-tango

I have been using Tango to perform motion tracking and camera feed capture using a modified TangoCameraPreview class. I recently need to add depth sensing feature into my app. I started with modifying the TangoConfig bysetting KEY_BOOLEAN_DEPTH and KEY_INT_DEPTH_MODE to true. However, the app starts to crash without me even starting to add code to onPointCloudAvailable(). I also got the following error message.

```
04-01 23:32:15.088 5651-5664/edu.umich.engin.droplab.embeddeddatalogger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallVoidMethodV called with pending exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String android.os.IBinder.getInterfaceDescriptor()' on a null object reference
04-01 23:32:15.088 5651-5664/edu.umich.engin.droplab.embeddeddatalogger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at void com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoPointCloudData.readFromParcel(android.os.Parcel) (TangoPointCloudData.java:157)
04-01 23:32:15.088 5651-5664/edu.umich.engin.droplab.embeddeddatalogger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at void com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoPointCloudData.<init>(android.os.Parcel) (TangoPointCloudData.java:112)
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? Thanks!

Update 4/5/2017:
Code:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(TAG, "onResume");
    if (askingPermission == false) {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(100);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(100);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient,
                        builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(this);
        startBackgroundThread();
        if (mBackgroundLogger == null) {
            mBackgroundLogger = new BackgroundLogger();
        }
        if (mPlayLocationListener == null) {
            mPlayLocationListener = new PlayLocationListener();
        }
        sensorHandler.post(mBackgroundLogger);
        sensorHandler.post(new recordButtonOnClickListener());
        startNewTango();
    }
}

 protected void startNewTango(){
    assert mTango == null;
    mTango = new Tango(Recording.this, new Runnable() {
        // Pass in a Runnable to be called from UI thread when Tango is ready, this Runnable
        // will be running on a new thread.
        // When Tango is ready, we can call Tango functions safely here only when there is no UI
        // thread changes involved.
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (Recording.this) {
                try {
                    mConfig = setupTangoConfig(mTango);
                    mTango.connect(mConfig);
                    startupTango();
                } catch (TangoOutOfDateException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.exception_out_of_date), e);
                } catch (TangoErrorException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.exception_tango_error), e);
                } catch (TangoInvalidException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.exception_tango_invalid), e);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
private TangoConfig setupTangoConfig(Tango tango) {
    // Create a new Tango Configuration and enable the HelloMotionTrackingActivity API.
    TangoConfig config = tango.getConfig(TangoConfig.CONFIG_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_MOTIONTRACKING, true);

    // Tango service should automatically attempt to recover when it enters an invalid state.
    config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_AUTORECOVERY, true);
    config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_COLORCAMERA, true);
    config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_DRIFT_CORRECTION, true);
    config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_LOWLATENCYIMUINTEGRATION, true);
    config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_DEPTH, true);
    config.putInt(TangoConfig.KEY_INT_DEPTH_MODE, TangoConfig.TANGO_DEPTH_MODE_POINT_CLOUD);
    return config;
}

private void startupTango() {
    // Lock configuration and connect to Tango
    // Select coordinate frame pair
    final ArrayList<TangoCoordinateFramePair> framePairs =
            new ArrayList<TangoCoordinateFramePair>();
    framePairs.add(new TangoCoordinateFramePair(
            TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE,
            TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE));
    mTangoCameraPreviewRecorder.connectToTangoCamera(mTango,TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR);
    // Listen for new Tango data
    mTango.connectListener(framePairs, new OnTangoUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPoseAvailable(final TangoPoseData pose) {
            //logPose(pose);
            tangoPose = true;
            tangoTranslation = pose.getTranslationAsFloats();
            tangoOrientation = pose.getRotationAsFloats();
            if(!firstFrame){
                String csvString = "5,"+ System.currentTimeMillis()+","+tangoTranslation[0]+","+tangoTranslation[1]+","+tangoTranslation[2]+","+tangoOrientation[0]+","+tangoOrientation[1]+","+tangoOrientation[2]+","+tangoOrientation[3]+"\r\n";
                csvWriteHandler.post(new CsvBackgroundWriter(csvString));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onXyzIjAvailable(TangoXyzIjData xyzIj) {
            // We are not using onXyzIjAvailable for this app.
        }

        @Override
        public void onPointCloudAvailable(TangoPointCloudData pointCloud) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Point Cloud");
            // We are not using onPointCloudAvailable for this app.
        }

        @Override
        public void onTangoEvent(final TangoEvent event) {
            // Ignoring TangoEvents.
        }

        @Override
        public void onFrameAvailable(int cameraId) {
            //Log.d(TAG, "onFrameAvailable");
            mTangoCameraPreviewRecorder.onFrameAvailable();
            if(isRecording){
                if(firstFrame){
                    firstFrame = false;
                    String csvString = "First Frame:" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "\r\n";
                    csvString = "0:gyro,1:acc,2:linAcc,3:ori,4:gps, 5:Tango\r\n" + csvString;
                    csvWriteHandler.post(new CsvBackgroundWriter(csvString));
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @azizbekian , I have uploaded my code. Would you please take a look at it? Thanks!

Comment: are you running an outdated TangoCore? Try update the TangoCore on your device.

Comment: @JasonGuo
I just updated my TangoCore. It still outputs the same error message.